# Component not storing element into variable (maybe it's not rendered yet?)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store a DOM element in a variable inside a React component.

I'm declaring this variable inside the `render()` function of the component, like this:

```
render() {
  const aside = document.querySelector('aside');
    ...
    ...
}
```

Given that this is declared before the `return`, I'm guessing that, at the time of this declaration, `const aside` is `null`, and maybe that's why this isn't working.

Where should I be declaring this variable? Or is there a better way to store variables of DOM elements like this in React?

Side question: would this variable be in reference to the browser DOM element or React's virtual DOM element?

Here is the full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    const aside = document.querySelector('aside');

    function hideSidebar() {
      aside.classList.remove('show');
    }

    function openSidebar() {
      aside.classList.add('show');
      aside.addEventListener('mouseleave', 'hideSidebar');
    }

    return (
        <aside>
          <svg onClick={openSidebar}
            ...
          </svg>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Dreamcast</li>
            <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Jetson</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

When I click on the `<svg>` element and it triggers `onClick={openSidebar}`, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that you are getting a `null` result because the DOM has not yet been updated at the time of `render` being called. When you need a reference to the raw DOM element, React provides the concept of a Ref to safely do so. You can read about Refs and how to use them in the official React documentation under [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

In most cases, React provides us with better alternatives than manually manipulating the DOM like this. For your situation described above, I would strongly recommend using component state to hold a value (ex. `isSidebarOpen`) and toggle the `className` based on this state property. Something similar to the example below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isSidebarOpen: false,
    };

    this.openSidebar = this.openSidebar.bind(this);
    this.hideSidebar = this.hideSidebar.bind(this);
  }

  openSidebar() {
    this.setState({
      isSidebarOpen: true,
    });
  }

  hideSidebar() {
    this.setState({
      isSidebarOpen: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    let asideClassName = this.state.isSidebarOpen
      ? 'show'
      : 'hide';

    return (
        <aside className={asideClassName} onMouseLeave={this.hideSidebar}>
          <svg onClick={this.openSidebar}
            ...
          </svg>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Dreamcast</li>
            <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Jetson</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Will be referring to this a lot today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not a good idea to manipulate the dom directly inside the React component.
In addition to the original answer, you can use react hooks as well - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Sidebar() {
  const [sideBarOpen, setSideBarOpen] = useState(false);

  const hideSideBar = () => {
    setSideBarOpen(false);
  };

  const showSideBar = () => {
    setSideBarOpen(true);
  };

  const chooseSvg = () => {
    //
  };

  return (
    <aside className={sideBarOpen ? "show" : "hide"} onMouseLeave={hideSideBar}>
      <svg onClick={showSideBar}>
        //...
      </svg>
      <ul>
        <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Dreamcast</li>
        <li onClick={chooseSvg}>Jetson</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```